# python, pandas, use groupby to compute mean in df with multi index

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider the following dataframe:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
dic={'volume': {('E7', Timestamp('2016-11-01 00:00:00')): Decimal('1204'),
  ('E7', Timestamp('2016-08-16 00:00:00')): Decimal('1070'),
  ('G6', Timestamp('2016-08-17 00:00:00')): Decimal('1702'),
  ('G6', Timestamp('2016-08-18 00:00:00')): Decimal('1262'),
  ('G6', Timestamp('2016-08-26 00:00:00')): Decimal('3333'),
  ('VG', Timestamp('2016-08-31 00:00:00')): Decimal('1123'),
  ('VG', Timestamp('2016-09-01 00:00:00')): Decimal('1581'),
  ('VG', Timestamp('2016-09-02 00:00:00')): Decimal('1276'),
  ('VG', Timestamp('2016-09-06 00:00:00')): Decimal('2417'),
           }}
df=pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

[image]

I would like for each symbol (the first column) to compute the mean of the "volume" column.

I tried `df.groupby(level=0).mean()` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Decimal in Pandas - it's not a native Numpy/Pandas dtype:

```
In [32]: df.dtypes
Out[32]:
volume     object   # <---- NOTE
dtype: object
```

convert it to numeric:

```
In [29]: df['vol'] = pd.to_numeric(df.volume)

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
              volume     vol
E7 2016-08-16   1070  1070.0
   2016-11-01   1204  1204.0
G6 2016-08-17   1702  1702.0
   2016-08-18   1262  1262.0
   2016-08-26   3333  3333.0
VG 2016-08-31   1123  1123.0
   2016-09-01   1581  1581.0
   2016-09-02   1276  1276.0
   2016-09-06   2417  2417.0

In [31]: df.mean(level=0)
Out[31]:
        vol
E7  1137.00
G6  2099.00
VG  1599.25
```